# smbclient python ошибка ValueError: src must be an absolute path to where the file should be copied from

Tags: python, python-3.x, smb

Использую smbclient и функцию smbclient.copyfile для копирования файлов на удалённый сервер (на вопрос почему именно через smb, такие требования)

```
smbclient.copyfile("C:\\test.png", f"\\{server}\\scaner\\", username=f"{pass_user}", password=f"{pass_user}")
```

Появляется ошибка:

```
ValueError: src must be an absolute path to where the file should be copied from.
```

При этом соединение с smb стабильно, папки через smbclient.mkdir создаются.

Пожалуйста подскажите в чем может быть проблема.

```
import smbclient
pass_user = 'user'
server = 'address'
smbclient.register_session(server, username=pass_user, password=pass_user)
#smbclient.mkdir(f"\\{server}\\scaner\\test", username=f"{pass_user}", password=f"{pass_user}")
smbclient.copyfile("C:\\test.png", f"\\{server}\\scaner\\test.png", username=f"{pass_user}", password=f"{pass_user}")
```

Comment: Мб дело в слешах: `r"C:\\test.png", fr"\\{server}\\scaner\\"`. А если pass_user строка, то f-строки нафиг не нужны, т.е. `username=pass_user, password=pass_user` :)

Comment: Какая библиотека? pysmb? Добавьте минимальный код вместе с импортами

Comment: @gil9red smbprotocol

Comment: Ага, нашел эту библиотеку и ту ошибку: https://github.com/jborean93/smbprotocol/blob/73d0d00e6948b57e3927d428bf6fc020b6102b0a/src/smbclient/_os.py#L131 Похоже, copyfile работает на удаленной машине, т.е. для того, чтобы отправить файл нужен другой метод

Comment: @gil9red подскажите пожалуйста какой метод в связке с smb можно использовать

Comment: Вы еще не предоставили всю запрошенную инфу: "Добавьте минимальный код вместе с импортами". А так, ваша ошибка есть тут https://github.com/jborean93/smbprotocol/issues/160, и, согласно, комментарию в ней нужно использовать не `smbclient.copyfile`, а `smbclient.copyfile.shutil` (поэтому импорты тоже нужно указывать :) )

Comment: @gil9red 

import smbclient

pass_user = 'user'
server = 'address'
# Optional - register the credentials with a server (overrides ClientConfig for that server)
smbclient.register_session(server, username=pass_user, password=pass_user)

#smbclient.mkdir(f"\\{server}\\scaner\\test", username=f"{pass_user}", password=f"{pass_user}")

smbclient.copyfile("C:\\test.png", f"\\{server}\\scaner\\", username=f"{pass_user}", password=f"{pass_user}")

Comment: И еще... в `copyfile`, второй параметр должен быть путем к файлу, а не папке. В описании функции библиотеки есть явное указание об этом https://github.com/jborean93/smbprotocol/blob/73d0d00e6948b57e3927d428bf6fc020b6102b0a/src/smbclient/_os.py#L124 и https://github.com/jborean93/smbprotocol/blob/73d0d00e6948b57e3927d428bf6fc020b6102b0a/src/smbclient/shutil.py#L121

Comment: Обновите текст вопроса, добавив тот код. Комментарии для этого плохо предназначены

Comment: @gil9red Добавил код к вопросу, попробовал через smbclient.copyfile.shutil перед этим импортировав shutil  не получилось ошибка AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'shutil'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переписал код, но не проверял:

```
import smbclient
from smbclient import shutil as smb_shutil

pass_user = 'user'
server = 'address'

smbclient.register_session(server, username=pass_user, password=pass_user)

smb_shutil.copyfile(
    r"C:\\test.png", rf"\\{server}\\scaner\\test.png", 
    username=pass_user, password=pass_user
)
```

Comment: Получилось! Большое спасибо вам за помощь!)

Comment: @a.sh, пожалуйста :)